# Exposing express var in Node.js Express.js server

Tags: node.js, express

Normally we use this code to startup an Express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

however I was looking through the Express docs and it seems like the only reason to expose the express variable is for static assets as in

```
express.static
```

so I was thinking of just using

```
var app = require('express')();
```

is there any good reason to expose the express var other than static assets?

Comment: also `express.Router`.  If you don't need either one of these then there's no reason to create the symbol ... but honestly it's not a big deal.  There's no reason *not* to create it.  You might need `static` or `Router` later after all.

Comment: this was more for my understanding than saving one line of code but yeah